# Is Spark DAG execution order in parallel or sequential?

Tags: apache-spark

I have two sources, they can be different type of sources(database or files)  or can be of same type.

Dataset1 = source1.load;

Dataset2 = source2.load;

Will spark loads the data parallelly into different datasets or will it load in sequence?

Comment: I believe spark doens't start loading immediately, it just starts building your lineage graph until you do some actions. By then it knows about all the load operations, transformations that should happen and it can optimize and do in parallel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Actions** occur sequentially. Your statement *... will load parallel into different datasets ...* has as answer sequentially as these are **Actions**.

**Data pipelines** required for **Actions** including the **Transformations**, occur in parallel where possible. E.g. creating a Data Frame with 4 loads that are subject to Union, say, will cause those loads to occur in parallel, provided enough Executors (Slots) can be allocated.

So, as the comment also states, you need an **Action** and the **DAG** path will determine flow and any **parallelism** that can be applied. You can see that in the Spark UI.

To demonstrate:

```
rdd1 = get some data
rdd2 = get some other data
rdd3 = get some other other data
rddA = rdd1 union rdd2 union rdd3
rddA.toDF.write ...

// followed by 

rdd1' = get some data
rdd2' = get some other data
rdd3' = get some other other data
rddA' = rdd1 union rdd2 union rdd3
rddA'.toDF.write ...
```

rddA'.toDF.write ... will occur after rddA.toDF.write... None of rdd1' and rdd2' and rdd3' Transformations occur in parallel with rddA.toDF.write 's Transformations / Action. That cannot be the case. This means that if you want write parallelism you need two separate SPARK apps - running concurrently - provided resources allow that of course.